# Having problems installing R package due to accented username

Tags: windows-10, packages, rstudio

I am working with RStudio on Windows 10 and trying to install package "hms" with no success. It seems that the problem is with my accented name in the Users account. Here is the error:

```
* installing *source* package 'hms' ...
** package 'hms' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Lums/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-hms/00new/hms/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'hms'
* removing 'C:/Users/Luís/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/hms'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
```

So, contrary to similar problems that I found by googling (where the error is in the creation of a folder for the package in the users folder with accented letter), it seems here that after dowloading the file, it cannot reach it due to the accented letter (its changes Luís to Lums in the path). What can I do to solve this problem? (this is not a problem specific to the hms package as I think I have already encountered the same problem some months ago with other package)

Comment: Install it somewhere else, for example `c:\apps\R`

Comment: But this doesn't solve the specific problem, it's more a workaround. I managed to install the package directly from R Gui.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by specifying the default homedir before installing packages :

```
Sys.setenv(HOME = "C:/Users/Rémi/Documents")
```

I found this here  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732049/change-home-directory-for-r